# Optaplanner 7 ConstraintStream reward according to value from function per instance

Tags: constraints, optaplanner

I am planning a schedule using Optaplanner 7.37, and am implementing a positive soft constraint, such that higher priority tasks get scheduled first. I want to do incremental score calculation, which rewards according to the priority value.

I have tried the following, but as you can see, it will just add one soft score unit per task scheduled (so it won't vary according to the Task's priority.

```
private Constraint scheduleHighPriorityTasks(ConstraintFactory factory) {
    return factory.from(ShiftAssignment.class)
            .reward('High priority work done', HardSoftScore.ONE_SOFT);
}
```

I would want something roughly like this fictional code:

```
private Constraint scheduleHighPriorityTasks(ConstraintFactory factory) {
    return factory.from(ShiftAssignment.class)
            .multiply(ShiftAssignment::getTaskPriority)
            .reward('High priority work done', HardSoftScore.ONE_SOFT);
}
```

such that if getTaskPriority returns a priority of 3, then the soft score will be rewarded by 3 times the configured weighting.

I don't think my requirements are that complex, so I think there probably is a way to do this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no other soft constraints, you can just use the overloaded reward method that accepts a matchWeigher:

```
private Constraint scheduleHighPriorityTasks(ConstraintFactory factory) {
    return factory.from(ShiftAssignment.class)
            .reward('High priority work done', HardSoftScore.ONE_SOFT, ShiftAssignment::getTaskPriority);
}
```

If there are other soft constraints, but this is *always* more important, then this isn't a soft constraint, but a medium constraint (and there are no other medium constraints).

If there are other soft constraints that can outweight or not outweigh this priority constraint, then it gets a bit more complex. I'd probably  use getTaskPrioritySoftWeight instead of getTaskPriority in that case.